# javascript input via native popup

Tags: javascript

In the past, I've seen javascript `alert()` style popups but they had input fields in them.

These forms are much like the primitive username/password field inputs you see when an `.htpasswd` file is used.

Can someone tell me how to implement this using regular javascript? (No libraries please)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you're thinking of [`prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.prompt).  It's just:

```
var userInput = prompt("text to display", "default input text");
```

Note that this is just a general input mechanism.  It's separate from the authentication dialog, though the underlying browser code may use the same GUI controls.

Comment: It doesn't ask for `user` and `password`.

Comment: @Bruno, he said "very much like."  I think the question is general, and he just means the appearance is similar.

Comment: @BrunoLMI didn't get the impression that the question was looking specifically for a username/password box, just a text input box.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Googling for "javascript input form" (or other related terms) wasn't much help.